# Автоматическая генерация формы

Tags: lsfusion

Есть несколько объектов. Определяю их с помощью метакода defineNamedObject. Каждый объект имеет как одинаковые свойства(например name) так и отличающиеся. Можно ли как-то присвоить свойства какой-то группе и потом всю группу вывести на форму(не автоматически сгенерированную, а определенную самостоятельно)? Можно с первичными свойствами работать как с коллекцией?

Comment: Добрый день! Вы не могли бы уточнить, что имеете ввиду под "работать как с коллекциями"?

Comment: Допустим обойти все свойства в цикле и совершить какое-то действие над всеми. В качестве примера показать имя текущего свойства с помощью MESSAGE. Или в цикле назначить все свойства такой-то форме.

Comment: Так, тогда нужно еще уточнить, "текущее свойство" - это свойство, на котором сейчас фокус ввода находится на форме или что-то другое? Тут просто небольшая путаница с терминологией, в вопросе написано "первичными свойствами". Такой термин есть в lsfusion: https://ru-documentation.lsfusion.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=688168, но, видимо, вы не это имеете ввиду.

Comment: Если обходить в цикле коллекцию свойств то текущее свойство - текущий элемент коллекции(позиция итератора). Это имелось в виду.

Comment: Как я понял свойства - это не объекты первого класса, поэтому создать из них коллекцию не получится.

Comment: Обновленная ссылка: https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Data_properties_DATA/

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли как-то присвоить свойства какой-то группе и потом всю группу
> вывести на форму

Нет, такой возможности нет. В частном случае, если нам нужно, например, добавлять более-менее фиксированный набор свойств для разных классов параметров, то можно создать метакод, в котором будет `EXTEND FORM` с `PROPERTIES` блоком, добавляющим эти свойства.

> Можно с первичными свойствами работать как с коллекцией?

Да. В модуле `Reflection` объявлен класс `Property`, по объектам которого можно итерироваться (также там есть классы и для некоторых других абстракций). Там вы сможете посмотреть, какие есть свойства, в которые параметром передаются объекты класса `Property`. Также практически все эти свойства есть на форме `Reflection.properties`, которую можно открыть из навигатора: `Администрирование > Метаданные > Свойства` (если у вас вдруг в этой форме пусто, то убедитесь, что в конфигурации, с помощью которой запускаете проект, отключена опция `Light start`).

С помощью Reflection можно программно, например, настроить политику безопасности, скрыть какие-то свойства на форме или сделать какие-то выборки. Но добавить на форму свойства таким образом не получится, так как объекты Reflection-классов - это просто отображение существующих на старте сервера объектов (в данном случае свойств), а добавление на форму - это по сути создание нового объекта "свойство на форме".

Comment: Понято, спасибо за разъяснение.